# Tableview allow only limitted checkbox button

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using limit option in tablview using swift.
for example:
If limit value contain "2" only two checkbox will able to select remaining checkbox will not able to select and
If limit value contain "0" all checkbox will able to select

Comment: add  the error you got and other codes related to this error

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:
Fom these line:  let cell: MultiOnlinecell = self.onlinediscountmultiarraytableview.cellForRow(at: index) as! MultiOnlinecell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to assign **nil** values to something.You are using **!** in your code. It is hard unwrapping.If you use this mark 100% make sure your value is there.If you not sure use optional unwrapping.

Not Use,

```
let cell: MultiOnlinecell = self.onlinediscountmultiarraytableview.cellForRow(at: index) as! MultiOnlinecell
```

Use this, It is save you from app crash

```
let cell: MultiOnlinecell = self.onlinediscountmultiarraytableview.cellForRow(at: index) as? MultiOnlinecell ?? UITableViewCell()
```

Comment: remove ! and try what I explain everywhere in your code

Comment: update your Data array and call myTable.reloadData()